# How to pass two onClick parameters to one function in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, onclick

I have a function called **Test** and I want to pass two onClick references to it.

```
const Test = ({ onConnect }:{ onConnect:any }, { onDisconnect }:{ onDisconnect:any }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <DrawDiagram />
      <button onClick={onConnect}>Connect</button>
      <button onClick={onDisconnect}>Connect</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

When I want to call it with the following code

```
  <Test 
  onConnect={() => sendEvent("CONNECT")} 
  onDisconnect={() => sendEvent("DISCONNECT")} 
  />;
```

It complains with this error message

```
(JSX attribute) onDisconnect: () => void
Type '{ onConnect: () => void; onDisconnect: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { onConnect: any; }'.
  Property 'onDisconnect' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { onConnect: any; }'.ts(2322)
```

It seems that I am not calling the function properly. How do I do this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current component is written as though the props will be passed as separate parameters. However, all props are combined into just one parameter. Here's the correct way to do it:

```
interface TestProps {
  onConnect: () => void;
  onDisconnect: () => void;
}

const Test = ({ onConnect, onDisconnect }: TestProps) => {
```